# VBA - Creating a dynamic path for an Image

Tags: image, vba, path

Could someone please help me create a path for an image that I am displaying in the image box? This tool is intended for use of others. Therefore, they will have to download it in their computers and the path to the image will change. I have tried several ways but nothing seems to work. Here is the code:

```
Me.cmdImage2.Picture = LoadPicture("G:\Pedestrian Bridges\New folder with organization\Visual Basic Tool\Tool\New folder\TRB paper Version\Imagenes Finales\Alternative 2.JPG")
```

Thanks a lot!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try thisworkbook.path or activeworkbook.path it will be saved the image in same folder

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question and something I've been recently working on. I will show you a few lines of my code that would be beneficial for you to use as well.

**The first potential method you could use would be to implement the IO class's ability to return the path your application is being run from.** You can do that by following this example:

```
 MessageBox.Show(IO.Path.Combine(IO.Directory.GetParent(Application.ExecutablePath).FullName, "myimage.jpg"))
```

**Another potential solution would be to use environmental variables.**

In order to do this you will need to import the IO class:

```
using System.IO;
```

Then you can reference environmental variables like this:

```
DirectoryInfo dst = new   DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("UserProfile") + @"\Desktop\!#!Desktop_Cleanup\" + s + @"_Desktop\" + category);
Sorters.CopyFiles(src, dst, true, "*."+ extension);
```

In my example, I'm using the UserProfile enviromental variable that is stored in Windows. Then, knowing where that path leads I am able to add a path to a file system on my desktop that I use for cleaning the desktop. Keep in mind you will need to use the `@` symbol before strings containing backslashes so they will be read properly and not as escape characters.

Sorters is a class that I made and won't be applicable in your application, but I included that line so you could see a possible implementation of the DirectoryInfo you create.

Hope this helps!